# Notify facebook application admin when comments are posted using social plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to send notification to facebook application admins when comments are 
posted using facebook social comments plugin?

Comment plugin is set up this way:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="111,222,333" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789" />

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470" notify="true"></div>

<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(){ 
             FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){
                   alert(response); 
             });
    };
</script>
```

Event subscribe works pretty good in this example(shows response alert), but is it possible to send notification to application administrators?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: how to store FB comments in our local DB while posting a comment. Please advice.

Comment: @user2003356 ask a question, not a comment.

Answer (score 5):

I set up a simple PHP script to email me whenever a comment is posted. The PHP is like this:

```
<?php
mail('me@example.com','facebook_notification.php',
'Comment activity on http://example.com'.$_GET['path']);
```

and this JavaScript passes the URL of the comment page to the PHP script:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){
var dummyImage = new Image;
dummyImage.src = 'http://example.com/facebook_notification.php?path='+response.href.replace('http://','');
});
```

I can easily add more addresses if I need to.

Comment: How to store FB comments in our local DB while posting a comment. Please advice.