# FB.event.subscribe comment.create acting without action from user

Tags: php, facebook, if-statement, comments

OK, so here is my problem. I'm trying to get an email sent to the author of individual posts once a comments is made in facebook comments (to notify the author that comments have been made). The comment box is in a K2 item (in Joomla).

FB.event.subscribe comment.create is working, I've tried it with just
alert('fired');
and that works fine. But when I enter the PHP it just starts sending emails to the first email given everytime someone enters the page. How do I get it to send email only when a comment is created or added?

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(){ 
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){
            <?php
                if ($this->item->author->name = 'Author1'){
                    $to = "author1@mydomain.com";
                }else if ($this->item->author->name = 'author2'){
                    $to = "author2@mydomain.com";
                };
                $subject = "Test mail";
                $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message. live run";
                $from = "admin@mydomain.com";
                $headers = "From:" . $from;
                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            ?>;
        });
    };
</script>
```

**EDIT**
Please follow this link [PHP variable from external file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992143/php-variable-from-external-file) for a complete solution on this subject and what I was trying to accomplish here.

Comment: How was I supposed to deduct the answer below from the link above?? This is NOT a duplicate! This is a specific question, compared to the one made in the the link above. The answer below is useful, the link above most definitely is not.

Comment: You were supposed to search the site to avoid asking duplicate questions. The people picked wrong duplicate, what now, sue them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is executed *server-side*. By the time the callback is fired, the PHP has already executed (when the page was requested).

Instead, you need to make an AJAX call inside of your callback to a PHP script that will do whatever it is that you need it to do:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){ 
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){
        $.post('/sendemail.php');
    });
};
```

Put the rest of your code in `sendemail.php`

This assumes you are using jQuery.

**Note:** This is a pretty bad idea considering that, without any validation, a user can just send repeated requests to `sendemail.php` and spam the heck out of someone's mailbox. Consider security, rate limiting, etc.

Comment: THANK YOU! I see what I was missing now. However, this poses a new "problem"... Now the "$this->item->author->name" (in the new sendmail.php file) isn't working anymore (i guess at least, since no emails are being sent). Not that proficient in PHP, but I'm guessing thats because "$this->item->author->name" referes to a variabel in the OTHER (the one with the FB.event.subscribe) php file.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?
Yes, I understand that someone could spam if they wanted to, but they have to use their facebook account for that  ;)  can't do it anonymously

Comment: This is where I'm at now in regards to solving all of this :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992143/php-variable-from-external-file
Thanks again for everybodys help!